# On Inspect element records are visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using server side pagination for my application. When the page is first loaded, i don't see any records, i can just see `pagination` bar.

I have seen that records are coming properly. But when i do `Inspect element` by `f12` suddenly records become visible.

How come this happen?

```
<div data-ng-controller="PracticeCtrl" data-ng-init="listPractices(1)">

                    <div class="col-sm-3 card" data-ng-repeat="practice in practices">
                        <div class="cardHeader">{{practice.name}}</div>
                        <div class="cardBody">
                            {{practice.practicename}}<br />
                            {{practice.createdon}}<br />
                            {{practice.status}}<br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
              <br style="clear: both;" />

                    <div class="pagination pagination-centered text-left">
                        <pagination num-pages="noOfPages" current-page="currentPage" on-select-page="listPractices(page)"></pagination>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: In which browser? Can you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: On Google Chrome...It uses `server side` data..so i cannot create a fiddle..

Comment: Can't you use the [backend mocking service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) for a fiddle? (Although you could first check if the problem doesn't also occur when you add test-data to the scope directly)

Comment: I got the solution...it was `<br>` statement which was creating problem.